# Need help to move elements from stack to queue (linkedlist)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, computer-science

So basically after processing the order (case 6), my game is deleted from the queue and moved into stack, and now i need to retrieve it back (case 7). i am struggling with moving back my item from stack and move it back into queue again (which is my game list) can anyone help me with this? and also i keep receiving warning message that says this:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>         temp=stack;

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list{
    char gName[30];
    struct list *next;
};

struct customer{
    int orderid;
    char cust_name[30];
    char gName[30];
    struct customer *next;
};

typedef struct list game;
typedef struct customer order;

int main()
{
    game *g, *gStart=NULL, *gcurrent;
    order *o, *oStart=NULL, *ocurrent, *stack=NULL, *scurrent;
    game *temp;
    int choice,count=1;

    while(1){
    printf("\nWhat would you like to do?\n");
    printf("(1) - Display the current stock\n");
    printf("(2) - Add a game to stock\n");
    printf("(3) - Display next order info\n");
    printf("(4) - Display all order\n");
    printf("(5) - Add order to queue\n");
    printf("(6) - Process the next order\n");
    printf("(7) - Reverse the last order\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: printf("\n------------------------------------------\n");
                if(gStart==NULL){
                printf("No games available...\n");
                }
                else{
                    gcurrent=gStart;
                    while(gcurrent!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Game name: %s\n",gcurrent->gName);
                        gcurrent=gcurrent->next;
                    }
                }
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
                break;

        case 2: g=(game*)malloc(sizeof(game));
                printf("\nEnter new game name : ");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(g->gName);
                g->next=NULL;

                if(gStart==NULL)
                    gStart=g;
                else{
                    gcurrent=gStart;
                    while(gcurrent->next!=NULL)
                        gcurrent=gcurrent->next;

                    gcurrent->next=g;
                }
                break;

        case 3: printf("------------------------------------------");
                if(oStart==NULL)
                    printf("\nNo orders available...\n");
                else{
                    printf("\nThe next order is for     : %s \n",oStart->cust_name);
                    printf("The game they ordered is  : %s \n",oStart->gName);
                }
                printf("------------------------------------------");
                break;

        case 4: printf("------------------------------------------");
                if(oStart==NULL)
                    printf("No orders available...\n");
                else {
                    ocurrent=oStart;
                    while(ocurrent!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("\nOrder ID %d\n",ocurrent->orderid);
                        printf("Customer name   : %s \n",ocurrent->cust_name);
                        printf("They ordered    : %s \n",ocurrent->gName);
                        ocurrent=ocurrent->next;
                    }
                }
                printf("------------------------------------------");
                break;

        case 5: o=(order*)malloc(sizeof(order));
                printf("\nEnter customer name       : ");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(o->cust_name);
                printf("Game you would like to order    : ");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(o->gName);
                o->orderid = count++;
                o->next=NULL;

                if(oStart==NULL)
                    oStart=o;
                else{
                    ocurrent=oStart;
                    while(ocurrent->next!=NULL)
                        ocurrent=ocurrent->next;

                    ocurrent->next=o;
                }
                break;

        case 6: if(stack==NULL){
                    stack=oStart;
                    oStart=oStart->next;
                }
                else{
                    temp=stack;
                    stack=oStart->next;
                    free(temp);
                }
                printf("\nProcessing order...\n");
                break;

        /*case 7: if(stack==NULL){
                    oStart=stack;
                    stack=stack->next;
                }
                else{
                    temp=oStart;
                    oStart=stack->next;
                    oStart->next=temp;
                }
                break;*/


    }
    }
}
```

Comment: No C++ content, so tag removed.

Comment: `game` is not `order`. What do you want to do?

Comment: yeah @MikeCAT ive fixed that thank you !